# problem with friendly URLs routing by name instead of ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, url-routing

I have a route in my code that looks like this:

```
map.app 'applications/:title_header', :controller => 'apps', :action => 'show'
```

I also changed my show method in the controller to be like this:

```
@app = App.find_by_title_header(params[:title_header])
```

If I type in `applications/title` things work fine. If I type in `applications/1` (valid Id) it fails (as expected)

However when I'm trying to use the friendly url helpers, in this case `app_path(@app)` the URLs that are generated look like `applications/1` . The only way I can get it to work is by putting in `app_path(@app.title_header)`. It seems like if it "just knows" that the ID is what's being passed out of the app object that it should "just know" that it should by default pass the name instead now. What do I need to change?

Comment: So what happens when you have friendly url "1234" which will coincide with ID?

Comment: You're assuming application is listed as a resource in routes.rb. Even then, route will use the first matching entry that describes the requested url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually what I ended up doing was not touching to_param. It was getting too ugly with other pages I had that needed the `to_param` to be an ID, not a permalink.

I ended up just passing the `@app.permalink` to the URL methods instead of touching `to_param`, but that one is still useful to know.

Answer (score 3):

Easiest, lightest solution is to just use to_param:

```
class Application < ActiveRecord::Base

  def to_param
    title_header.parameterize
  end

end
```

The String instance method `parameterize` will ensure the string is URL appropriate. Then, in your controllers you will just have to update all `find`s to use `find_by_title_header` instead of just `find`.

Make sure you're `title_header`s will be unique!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds about right. Rails doesn't assume that the symbols it encounters in a named route are methods on an object.

The best way around this is to add a custom helper to application_helper.rb, that creates takes the syntax you want to use and passes it on to a more basic version of url for.

```
def my_app_path(object, args)
  if object.responds_to? :title_header
    app_path(object.title_header, args)
  else 
    raise "Cannot generate url from object, missing title_header"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to define a to_param method on App, for one, but check out acts_as_friendly_param, which does that for you and more: http://chrisfarms.googlecode.com/svn/rails/plugins/acts_as_friendly_param/